# Completely stop Enterprise guide on condition

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

So, I have a simple project with one Program (user-writen code) and then one Add-Inn (custom task) (it is very useful System Command executor add-inn, about you can read [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2007/10/05/you-are-under-my-command-prompt/))

So, when I get some condition in Program step, I want to stop my Project. I could stop Program, for example, using

```
ENDSAS
```

or

```
Abort abend
```

but, even if Program immediately stops (with error message in log), Add-Inn is execute! How disable executing of Add-Inn on condition (on error or any other)?

Thanks

P.S. Project will be execute in batch mode

Comment: Curious what you mean by batch mode?  Do you mean you will schedule the project?  AFAIK,  EG doesn't have a concept of batch mode vs interactive, in the same way that DM SAS does.

Comment: Yes, I have vbs script that execute project, ant this script will be shedulated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an EG process flow, as you presumably are, then you need to set up a **condition** to run the add-in task.

Right click on your one program, select 'condition', add.  Let's say you have a macro variable that is set to 0 if you have no problems or (some value) if you have a problem.  (Could also use any of the automatic SYSERR type macro variables.)

Then, put your add-in task under "Then, run this task".  You can add an Else or Else If if you want, or just leave that as None.

Then, EG won't run your task unless the macro variable is successful.

[image: Example]